# Mysql PDO Connection to external server

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect a index.php to a Mysql server external.
I'm using:

```
$g_con = new PDO('mysql: host=mysql.domain.com;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'dbuser', 'dbpw');
```

But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dbname'@'app3.data-center.com' (using password: YES)

I think the problem is that i need to connect to mysql.domain.com (this is my hostname and phpmyadmin login for my external DB) and website show access denied for dbname @ app3.data-center.com and 'app3.data-center.com' is the web site hosting sever. Maybe my free hosting don't let me to connect to external db's or what?

Comment: If you're getting that error, then your script is successfully connecting to the database.  I think your username / password are just wrong.

Comment: either that or the user account itself is not set to allow external connections - in the user config you have to specify the host(s) which can use that username. You can put a wildcard (%) to allow all hosts. Check the mySQL docs for details. Probably the app should not be using the same credentials as you use for phpMyAdmin anyway - it will have too many privileges. Create a user account specifically for the PHP application which has only the rights it actually needs. Otherwise you're just creating a security risk for no reason.